# regexp(?) for Extract a URL from another URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need to check if there's a URL within a URL, and if so, extract it (the inner URL).

So, I need to check if this is a URL within a URL

```
http://www.outerURL.com/outerParameter1/x?u=http://innerURL.com/innerParameter1&outerParameter2/
```

and extract

```
http://innerURL.com/innerParameter1
```

without jquery. This is for clien-side javascript.

And hopefully make it fit into this template

```
var link;
link = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")

for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    if (
            // URL checking here
        ){
        //replacing here
        link[i].href = link[i].href.replace(/*  ??? */)
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if this will be done in regex alone, how should I go about this?

Comment: Is this even a valid URL? The http specs are not exactly easy to read, but shouldn't `http://innerURL.com/innerParameter1` be URLencoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-regex, assuming that syntax is fairly static:

```
var inner = link[i].href.indexOf('http://',1);
inner = inner>-1 ? link[i].href.substr(inner,link[i].href.indexOf('&',inner)-inner) : false;
```

`inner` will be false if an inner URL is not found, or the inner URL string if it is

Answer (score 1):

Something among the lines of :

```
var links = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = link[i].href,
        m = s.match(/.(http[^&]+)/); //link.match(/u=/u=(http:[^&]+)/);
    if (m){
        link.href = m[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: `[&$]` is not correct - `$` doesn't work this way. I'd suggest `/u=(http:[^&]+)/`

Comment: It also extracts out `/u=`

Comment: Yes, the u= part but that can change, sec.

Comment: Check the updated answer, basicly it will match the last string that starts with http

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
link[i].href = link[i].href.replace(/^.*?[?&]u=(http:.+?)(?:&.*|\/?)$/i, '$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/^[A-Z].+\?[A-Z]=(.*)&/gim
```

http://regex101.com/r/dF3rN5

Javascript

```
url = 'http://www.outerURL.com/outerParameter1/x?u=http://innerURL.com/innerParameter1&outerParameter2/';

replace = url.replace(/^[A-Z].+\?[A-Z]=(.*)&/gim, '$1');

// returns 'http://innerURL.com/innerParameter1outerParameter2/'
```